# Should this CW post be renamed?

Tags: support

I have encountered several questions that ask for "desktop recording tools". The most recent is [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/822868/308164). There is already a CW answer, [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/4428/308164), but it comes under the name of "screencast", which personally, as a non-native English speaker - and having lived in the UK for 5 years - is an unknown word to me. And it could also be a less intuitive word for native English speakers, and particularly for noobs (see below).

Now, a [quick internal search](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=record+desktop) does not bring up the aforementioned post under the "relevance" tab (the default one) **until the second page, using 50 items per page**. I comes first if the tab "votes" is selected, but the truth is that **[if you are noob enough not to solve this problem using google](http://bfy.tw/7cGQ) (which first result is the CW post)**, they will never find it using AU internal search.

Even more dramatic, if you want to ask a new question, the CW post **does not come up at all under the "Questions that may already have your answer" list**. I show this below, writing perhaps the most noob title. Please test it yourself if in doubt.

[image]

So, clearly that CW post **is not being reached by those who needed the most**.

**How can we change this? Can we change the title, tags, wording, or anything to make it the top post in the "relevance" AU search page, and, even more importantly, in the related questions' list?**

I'm sure some of you know how the search system and suggested questions work in order to solve this.

Comment: I edited the question to say `record desktop` rather than `screencast`. Screen casting, to my knowledge, is sending your phones display to another display, think "chromecast" or search "screen cast" on Google play, you will see what I mean, it seems to be confusing terminology. Now if you search "record + "screen", it should be top result. FYI, we don't answer what is "best" of something.

Comment: Also made a tag `record-screen`, to make them easy to find.

Comment: Great! That would do it. Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: IMHO being a native English speaker or a resident of the UK doesn't mean much when it comes to jargon. @Mark Chromecast definitely has one usage, but screencast I'd say is older. I have seen the term well before Chromecast devices existed, and then it was just recording your screen, usually desktop, for (possibly live) broadcast. Not necessarily phones.

Comment: @luchonacho IDK what to put in an answer to this. I thought about it for a couple of days but all I can really say is, now you are 2k you have earned the right to edit as you see fit, use that right, CW posts are for the community to edit at will.

Comment: @MarkKirby Yeah, I had the idea CW were "special", so just editing seemed too quick an approach.

Comment: A CW is an q or a that is opened to the community to add too, no one owns it and no one earns rep, it is there for you to edit as you see fit, more info http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Answer (score 3):

I agree wholeheartedly. In my mind, screencasting is broadcasting (or sending) your screen elsewhere. I can think of a number of reasons I might want to record my desktop but I would never search "screencast" unless my intent was to send that output elsewhere.