# Make [recording] a synonym of [record]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have two tags, one called [recording](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recording) and one called [record](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/record).

I propose [recording](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recording) become a synonym of [record](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/record).

[recording](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recording) has a few questions but no description or anything, while [record](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/record) is more fleshed out, and I don't see a need for both these tags.

Comment: I agree, and there have been many cases where users with 250+ rep ask a question and can create a custom tag, which leads to a high quantity of duplicates, or at least similar tags

Comment: Just as an update, I eventually did what I proposed (destroying both tags).

Answer (score 8):

#### I don't think either of those tags are useful.

We want tags to be used consistently to define the subject of questions, IMHO. The usage guidance for [record](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/record)  currently says:

> Questions about software for recording audio and video with Ubuntu.

Of the 98 questions with this tag, only [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428361/why-doesnt-ssh-record-failed-access-in-var-log-btmp) is **not** about recording audio, video or the desktop, or some user action. So I think there is no use for a tag [record](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/record) with a generic meaning or technical meaning as in a database record (disagreeing with [Lorenzo's answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/16113/527764)).

All of the questions in [recording](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recording) seem to be, once again, about recording audio, video, or the desktop.

I don't think these three topics are the same. We already have a tag [audio-recording](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/audio-recording) which is a subset of [recording](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recording). Desktop recording seems to me to be a totally distinct topic.

We have two separate tags being used for exactly the same purpose, failing to distinguish between three topics.

**My proposal is that we create two new tags, leaving these:**

[audio-recording](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/audio-recording) [video-recording](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/video-recording) [desktop-recording](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/desktop-recording)

And re-tag all of the posts (124 in total) appropriately (yes I am very willing to do this myself) to remove both [record](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/record) and [recording](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recording).

Comment: For desktop-recording, there's a tag called `screecast` at the moment, maybe make them synonyms in this case?

Comment: @Dan like the poster of [this meta question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16064/should-this-cw-post-be-renamed), I don't really know what a screencast is, but if you think it should be a synonym, maybe make a meta question about it

Comment: I will post one as soon I am back near my laptop. I just realized this post is over a year old. I hadn't noticed the date when I first commented.

Answer (score 4):

I agree. As recording and record {verbs} mean the same thing (creating a record {noun}) I see no valid reason whatsoever why we shouldn't proceed as you suggest.

If you have a score of 5 or higher in the tag please request it here: https://askubuntu.com/tags/record/synonyms

Comment: apologies for the unwarranted edit! I don't think anyone around has enough rep to suggest a synonym or vote on it, but I made a counter-suggestion anyway - do you have any views on that?

Comment: @Zanna I don't know if anyone has an answer score of 5 or higher in the tag either. (You know me, "Mister Any Tag, Any time") :-) Oxwivi comment and your logic both make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree. The tag [recording](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/recording) should replace the tag [record](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/record) in all questions about the audio/video recording, in combination with other tags like [audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/audio) or [video](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/video).
In fact when we speak of a "record" we may refer to a database record, to a meta-data record or to other similar constructs.

Comment: In either of those cases, the tags can be database and metadata respectively. Additional record tag adds no value whatsoever.

Comment: @Oxwivi yes, it's a very subtle difference ignored by many users. But, to be correct, we should add the "record" tag for the database users and eventually delete the "recording" tag to avoid confusion, because we already have other tags for the audio and video topics.
Two tags with the same meaning are a waste of time for the average user and a waste of resources for the servers. :-)