# How can one determine who has the highest score for a specific tag?

Tags: support

This question was prompted by [this one](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16065/make-recording-a-synonym-of-record) and I was wondering who if anyone has the required score in the tag to [request the synonym](https://askubuntu.com/tags/record/synonyms). I checked the tags of some likely suspects but came up empty. I'm wondering if there's a specific moderator tool that would answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you got to a tag's [info tab](https://askubuntu.com/tags/record/info) there is a sidebar for the "top answerers" in that tag:

> [image]

it doesn't tell you each person's outright score, but it will show you who can suggest synonyms (most likely, anyway).

Comment: Excellent. Now if we could just get @geppettvs-dconstanzo to chime in on this we might get it done.

Comment: Or @Takkat for that matter.

Comment: I notice that screencast has also been suggested as a synonym for record although that doesn't make near as much sense to me as recording. Related I could see, but synonymous? I don't think so.

Comment: You can get users' tag scores from their Profile→Tags page. You need to find it manually and the score is upvotes, not reputation... But tedious as that is, it's possible to do the lookup the OP is trying to do. If the top person can't, no mortal user can.